# cannot reference capture group in sed

Tags: sed

I want to append a character on to a string.

I have this:

```
sed -r "s/\(.+:.+\)/\1,f/" "123:abc"
```

I simply want to append a `,f` to the end of the string and am trying to reference the capture group `\(.+:.+\)`. But, it does not work. I keep getting this error when I try to reference the capture group `\1`:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

And idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using POSIX Basic syntax (with escaped parenthesis) when you specified the `-r` flag, which signifies POSIX Extended syntax.

[More on this subject](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)

Don't escape the parenthesis, and this should work.  Sed is complaining because it doesn't think there is a group to reference, but instead, that there are literal parenthesis to find.

```
... "s/(.+:.+)/\1,f/" ...
```

i.e.

```
>echo "123:abc" | sed -r "s/(.+:.+)/\1,f/"
123:abc,f
```

Comment: it's not emacs style, it's BRE. and your command is incomplete

Comment: OK... full example:
`$echo "123:abc" > /tmp/sample.txt`

`$sed -r "s/(.+:.+)/\1,f/" /tmp/sample.txt`
`123:abc,f`

Comment: Add that to your answer, not here. The command you posted doesn't have a closing quote, that's what I meant by *incomplete*

Comment: That works. Thanks guys. Please explain what BRE is and why using `\(` is not needed?

Comment: POSIX Basic syntax (as opposed to extended, which you get with the `-r` flag) https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html